# I am trying categorize data based on multiple column in pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have following new_correlation dataframe which contain following input

```
| Engagement Index | High Impact |
|------------------|-------------|
| 3.14             | 48.0        |
| 4.15             | 31.0        |
| 4.20             | 40.0        |
```

My condition is

```
def priority_driver(corr, high_impact):
    if corr > 0.4 & high_impact > 40:
        return 'Sustenance'
    elif corr > 0.4 & high_impact < 40:
        return 'Improvement'
    elif corr < 0.4 & high_impact > 40:
        return 'Distraction'
    elif corr < 0.4 & high_impact < 40:
        return 'Low Focus'
```

I tried `new_correlation['Priority of action'] = new_correlation.apply(lambda x: priority_driver(x['Engagement Index'], x['High Impact']), axis =1)`

This gives me

> **TypeError**: ("unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'float' and 'float'", 'occurred at index 0')

**Required output:**

```
| Engagement Index | High Impact | Priority of action |
|------------------|-------------|--------------------|
| 0.72             | 48.0        | Sustenance         |
| 0.74             | 31.0        | Improvement        |
| 0.78             | 40.0        | Sustenance         |
```

Comment: You need parenthesis to separate the conditions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write

```
if (corr > 0.4) & (high_impact > 40)
```

Alternatively, this should also work (and IMO is more readable):

```
if corr > 0.4 and high_impact > 40
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that there is also a possibility to do that with with `numpy select` which would look something like that :

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : pd.np.random.choice([.2, .3, .4, .5, .6, .7], 200),                                       
                   'B' : pd.np.random.randint(30, 50, 200)})

conds = [ (df['A'] >= .4) & (df['B'] >= 40),
          (df['A'] >= .4) & (df['B'] < 40),
          (df['A'] <= .4) & (df['B'] >= 40),
          (df['A'] <= .4) & (df['B'] < 40) ]

cond_resp = ['Sustenance', 'Improvement', 'Distraction', 'Low Focus']

df['C'] = np.select(conds, cond_resp)
```